# How to find answer to small numerical mapping of integers?

Tags: numbers, mapping

```
1207 -> 1
4691 -> 2
3508 -> 3
6446 -> 2 (repeat of 2)
9918 -> 4
8698 -> 6
3271 -> 0
8144 -> ?
```

Find what 8144 maps to!!!

Tried fitting functions on modular patterns as well as sum of digits, but all failed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an old numeric puzzle where the answer is the the amount of closed loops ( when written as text ) in the number,

So,

```
1 -> 0
2 -> 0
3 -> 0
4 -> 0 // in this font
5 -> 0
6 -> 1
7 -> 0
8 -> 2
9 -> 1
0 -> 1
```

Then simply apply this mapping for each digit and take the sum

For example

`1207` => 0 + 0 + 1 + 0 = 1

Or for you specific case

`8144` => 2 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 2